# WCF Endpoints determine which Auth method called

Tags: wcf, authentication

From inside a WCF Service can I determine the authentication method which called the service?

For example;

```
if (Forms Authentication) {
  //do something
}

if (WindowsAuthentication) {
  //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the `ServiceSecurityContext` on the `OperationContext` inside your WCF service class, and from that, you can determine how the user was authenticated (if at all).

```
ServiceSecurityContext security = 
      OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext;
```

Now you might have one of these on the security context:

- PrimaryIdentity. Contains the identity claim from the claim set, as a traditional IIdentity reference.
- WindowsIdentity. Contains the identity claim from the claim set if it is a WindowsIdentity.

If you have other authentication mechanisms (like certificates, or federated authentication), your `PrimaryIdentity` will contain a suitable identity for that mechanism.

See the [Fundamentals of WCF Security](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/33342/0/page/3) (link to page 3) for a great discussion of this topic.

Comment: Absolute legend thank you.  I shall try this first thing in the morning. (I'm on GMT)

Comment: Tried using this but the OperationContext.Current is null.  Does it need setting up somewhere?

Comment: @Mike Mengell: what kind of service do you have? SOAP or REST? What binding?

Comment: If your binding doesn't have any security set up, there's a chance the `PrimaryIdentity` and `windowsIdentity` - or the whole `ServiceSecurityContext` itself - would be NULL - but the `OperationContext` should always be present, AFAIK